# Omnikey 5421 can't read SLE4442

Tags: delphi, smartcard, winscard

I have contact *SLE4442* smart card (2W) and *Omnikey 5421* smart card reader.
My problem is with connection to card. WinSCard's method `SCardConnect` returns error `SCARD_W_UNRESPONSIVE_CARD 0x80100066`. What is interesting this problem not exist with *Omnikey 5**3**21* (predecessor 5421). I post code that I used to test read of data (Delphi):

```
function GetResponseFromCard(const FCardHandle: Integer; const APdu: 

string): string;
var
  RetVar : cardinal;
  SBuf   : string;
  SLen   : cardinal;
  RBuf   : string;
  RLen   : cardinal;
  Ppci   : Pointer;
begin
  SBuf := APdu;
  RBuf := StringOfChar(#0,260);
  Ppci := @SCARD_PCI_T0;
  SLen := Length(APdu);
  RLen := Length(RBuf);
  RetVar := SCardTransmit(FCardHandle, Ppci, Pointer(SBuf), SLen, nil, Pointer(RBuf), @RLen);
  if RetVar = SCARD_S_SUCCESS then begin
    Result := Copy(RBuf,1,RLen);
  end else begin
    Result := IntToHex(RetVar, 8);
  end;
end;

procedure TestSLE4442;
var
  FContext: Cardinal;
  PContext: Pointer;
  Res: LongInt;
  ReaderListStr: string;
  ReaderListSize: integer;
  v: array[0..10] of string;
  SelectedReader: PChar;
  phCard: Integer;
  pdwActiveProtocol: Integer;
  ReadedData: string;
begin
  FContext := 0;
  PContext := @FContext;

  Res := SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_USER, nil, nil, PContext);
  if Res = SCARD_S_SUCCESS then begin
    Res := SCardListReaders(FContext, nil, nil, ReaderListSize);
    if Res = SCARD_S_SUCCESS then begin
      SetLength(ReaderListStr, ReaderListSize);
      Res := SCardListReaders(FContext, nil, Pointer(ReaderListStr), ReaderListSize);
      SortOutSubstrings(ReaderListStr,v,[#0]);
      SelectedReader := PChar(v[0]);
      ShowMessage('SelectedReader: '+ SelectedReader);
      if Res = SCARD_S_SUCCESS then begin
        Res := SCardConnect(FContext, SelectedReader, SCARD_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0, phCard, @pdwActiveProtocol);
        if Res = SCARD_S_SUCCESS then begin
          ReadedData := GetResponseFromCard(phCard, TStringHelper.Hex2Bin('FFB0000000'));
          ShowMessage('Data: '+ ReadedData);
        end;
      end;
    end;
    SCardReleaseContext(FContext);
  end;
end;
```

Have someone met with this problem? I also asked HID but without answer for now.

Comment: It sounds to me like you have a problem between the card and the reader. Do you have any other software that proves this particular reader-card combination functions properly? We got some new RFID readers at work that no longer read my old ID badge, although the older readers continue to read it just fine. My solution was to get a new ID badge. Perhaps you need to replace your old card. Or maybe your new reader is faulty.

Comment: I tried couple of software to test connectivity also from HID. All of them have the same problem like me SCARD_W_UNRESPONSIVE_CARD. I don't have brand new clear card to test if this is a problem.

Comment: If all the programs fail to read the card, not just the program you wrote, then it's surely not a problem with your code, so the code you've provided here is irrelevant. Is there any *software question* you can post that's relevant to your problem? If so, then [edit] your question accordingly. Otherwise, it's off topic here.

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe with Omnikey 5421 we need use different SCardConnect parameters to work with 2W cards.

Comment: If I look at the data sheet of the OmniKey 5421 I see that it supports T=0 and T=1 protocols for contact-based interface. I see nothing indicating two-wire or three-wire support necessary for dumb memory cards. Why do you think, it is supported nevertheless?

Comment: Maybe. If I were you, I'd contact the vendor.

Comment: Have you heard about "Synchronous API" which is used for accessing synchronous card. This API is OMNIKEY’s proprietary.I am not sure but may be this is useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help. I heard and I tired Synchronous Omnikey API. Vendor answered me that 2WBP is not supported in new 5421. Maybe there is chance using SCARD_SHARE_DIRECT because using this I'm able to connect to SLE4442 using 5421. But this is hard to tell what I can do more without vendor support.